# Creating a dataframe from several .txt files - each file being a row with 25 values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-files

So, I have 7200 txt files, each with 25 lines. I would like to create a dataframe from them, with 7200 rows and 25 columns -- each line of the .txt file would be a value a column.

For that, first I have created a list *column_names* with length 25, and tested importing one single .txt file.

However, when I try this:
`pd.read_csv('Data/fake-meta-information/1-meta.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=column_names)`

I get 25x25 dataframe, with values only on the first column. How do I read this into the dataframe in a way that I can get the txt lines to be imputed as values into the columns, and not imputing everything into the first column and creating 25 rows?

My next step would be creating a **for loop** to append each text file as a new row.

Probably something like this:

```
dir1 = *folder_path*
list = os.listdir(dir1)
number_files = len(list)

for i in range(number_files):
        title = list[i]
        df_temp = pd.read_csv(dir1 + title, delim_whitespace=True, names=column_names)
        df = df.append(df_temp,ignore_index=True)
```

I hope I have been clear. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`read_csv` generates a row per line in the source file but you want them to be columns. You could read the rows and pivot to columns, but since these files have a single value per line, you can just read them in `numpy` and use each resulting array as a row in a dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

dir1 = Path(".")
df = pd.DataFrame([np.loadtxt(filename) for filename in dir1.glob("*.txt")])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

tdelaney's answer is probably "better" than mine, but if you want to keep your code more stylistically closer to what you are currently doing the following is another option.

You are getting your current output (25x25 with data in the first column only) because your read data is 25x1 but you are forcing the dataframe to have 25 columns with your `names=column_names` parameter.

To solve, just wait until the end to apply the column names:

1. Get a 25x1 df (drop the names param):

   `df_temp = pd.read_csv(dir1 + title, delim_whitespace=True)`
2. Append the 25x1 df forming a 25x7200 df: `df = df.append(df_temp,ignore_index=True)`
3. Transpose the df forming the final 7200x25 df: `df=df.T`
4. Add column names: `df.columns=column_names`